# Selection Axis failure in loop

Tags: bpel

I have tried using *while* loop in BPEL process designer.I'm assigning the response to a variable and concatenating that in an output string. It shows in the console that response is received on invoking the service(which returns muliple items) but Gives **SelectionAxis Failure** in the final response.

*OutputString* concatenates each time a response is recieved and displays final result as a string

Comment: OutputString concatenates each time a response is recieved and should display final result as a string but it is not

Comment: soapenv:Server axis2ns2:selectionFailure